# Swfit 3 : How can I get all items in the cell with button action?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a button in my cell and I want to get all of the items in the cell with this button.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. I hope you can get the idea that I want to do.

```
@IBAction func addToCardAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: menuTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow) as! SiparisVerTableViewCell
    print(cell.countLabel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button is in the cell itself, then things are really easy.

The super view of your button would be the content view of the table view cell and the super view of *that* will be the `UITableViewCell` itself.

So your method should look like this:

```
@IBAction func addToCardAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! SiparisVerTableViewCell
    print(cell.countLabel)
}
```

`tableView.dequeueReusableCell` will just create a new cell, so using it here will not do what you want.

Comment: this is what I'm looking for. It works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried again and sometimes it just works for the first row. do you have any idea about what the problem is? Is there any bug on xcode or what?

Comment: Is there a button in every row, or just the first row? Are all the buttons' targets set to this `IBAction` function? @jorjj

Comment: Yes, there is a button for every row and I have one IBAction for that.

Comment: @jorjj Okay, what do you mean by "not" work? Are you only getting no output when you press the other buttons?

Answer (score -1):

you can create protocol

```
protocol DataPasser: NSObjectProtocol {
    func passData(...any parameters)
}
```

your `UIViewController` should

```
extension MyViewController: DataPasser {
    func passData(...any parameters) {
        //manipulate it
    }
}
```

inside your `UITableViewCell` create

```
weak var dataDelegate: DataPasser?
```

link your `UIButton` action to your cell and inside it do

```
self.dataDelegate?.passData(...any parameters)
```

and inside `cellForRow` of your `UIViewController` do

```
cell.dataDelegate = self
```